# For any $x_0\in\mathbb{R},$ does there exist $f\in C_0^p(\mathbb{R})$ such that $f$ has compact support and prescribed derivatives?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Fix a natural number $p.$

Let $C_0^p(\mathbb{R})$ be a set of continuous functions $f$ such that $f,f',f'',...,f^{(p)}$ are continuous and $f$ vanishes at infinity.

Recall that support of $f$ is the closure of the set of points $x\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)\neq 0.$

> **Question:** Given any $x_0\in\mathbb{R},$ does there exist a function $f$ in $C_0^p(\mathbb{R})$ such that $f$ has compact support and $f^{(i)}(x_0)=0$ for all $0\leq i \leq p-2, f^{(p-1)}(x_0)= f^{(p)}(x_0)=1?$

If we ignore compact support, then we can use Taylor polynomial to obtain such $f.$

But with compact support, I have no idea how.

Comment: Just multiply the Taylor polynomial by a $C^\infty$ function that equals $1$ in some $(x_0-\delta, x_0+\delta).$

Answer (score 4):

Let $\varphi$ be a smooth cut-off function, i.e., $\varphi$ has compact support and $\varphi \equiv 1$ in a neighborhood of $x_0$. Moreover, denote by $T$ a polynomial satisfying your conditions on the derivative in $x_0$. Then, $f$ defined via $f(x) = \varphi(x) \, T(x)$ has the desired properties.

Comment: I see. Just a side question, if we want $f$ with compact support and $f^{i_0}(x_0) = f^{(p)}(x_0) =  1$ for some $0\leq i_0\leq p$ and $f^{(i)}(x_0) = 0$ for all $0\leq i \neq i_0 \leq p-1,$ can we use the same construction?

Comment: Yes, you can do the same thing.